# How to set date in parameter between past years and months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to prepare a report where I need to select data:

Current year - 1 between Current year - 10 AND Current month - 19

So I created parameters:

```
DECLARE @EvaluationYearOld int = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 10
DECLARE @EvaluationYearNew int = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1
DECLARE @EvaluationMonthCurrent int = Month(GETDATE()) - 19


SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE 
    year(raportdate) > @EvaluationYearOld
    AND year(raportdate) < @EvaluationYearNew
    AND month(raportdate) < @EvaluationMonthCurrent
```

It's not working well. I think there is problem with months.

Comment: EvaluationMonthCurrent will be between -18 and -7... month(raportdate) < @EvaluationMonthCurrent will never be true.

Comment: Unclear exactly which years and months you want. Do you only want 1 month per year? Or do you want to go back from the current month until the beginning of the year 10 years ago

Comment: Your month condition will skip months for each year involved...

Comment: @Charlieface I want date range between current year (2021)  - 1 = 2020 and current year (2021) - 10 = 2011. Selected data should be between 2020 and 2011 (in this year) and it's working. Problem is about adding currentmonth - 19

Comment: @ninjaloot777 . . . Your comment helps, but only a little.  Edit the question and show explicitly what data ranges you want for specific values of the parameters.

Comment: You haven't really answered me: what does "currentmonth - 19" refer to? You asked for years then you talk about months?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. Try it:

```
DECLARE @EvaluationYearOld int = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 10
DECLARE @EvaluationYearNew int = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1
DECLARE @EvaluationMonthCurrent int = Month(GETDATE()) - 7


SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE 
    year(raportdate) between @EvaluationYearOld
    AND @EvaluationYearNew
    AND month(raportdate) < @EvaluationMonthCurrent
```

And you have to use minus months that are smaller than 12. Because when you take 19 from month its like you take 1 year and 7 month from it. Then your condition might have some problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @EvaluationMonthCurrent int = Month(GETDATE()) - 19
```

In the above line MONTH(Date) function will return you interger in range 1 to 12 and you are subtracting 19 from them so if you take max value of MONTH(Date) i.e 12 then you get 12-19=-7 so for getting the value correct use this function

```
DECLARE @EvaluationMonthCurrent int = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-19,GETDATE()))
```

This will give you the correct value .

Comment: Yes its showin month corectly but using where clause its not filter well. It taking dates from 2011 etc

Comment: for that i need the value of reportdate column

Comment: Those value are like:
2019-02-08 00:00:00.000
2019-02-10 00:00:00.000
2019-02-12 00:00:00.000
2019-05-01 00:00:00.000
2019-03-13 00:00:00.000
2018-11-15 00:00:00.000

Comment: @ninjaloot777 all the value you given is worked fine in your query .  Please explain what is the date range you want and why you use month . As your code suggest you want date from 2011 to 2020 (excluding both) and also month is not equal to 12 (December) .